# Asynchronous Queue Based File Writing

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I'm writing a multi threaded program in Java, and have a single writer thread running alongside. Once the threads have processed a chunk of data, they write to the `LinkedBlockingQueue` in the writer thread via the `synchronized writeToFile` method in the `writer`.

The idea is that once the queue gets to a certain size, the threads are blocked from appending to the queue, and the data is output to the file. I am processing large amounts of data (20-50GB at a time), and this helps to reduce the RAM used. (If theres a better way to do this, i'm open to suggestions!)

The problem i'm having is that despite making the `writeToFile` method synchronized, and writing to file via the `emptyQueues` in a `synchonrized` block, the threads are still appending to the queue, whilst the thread is writing to the file.

```
@Component("writer")
public class WriterImpl implements Writer {

private boolean isRunning;
private PrintWriter fastQWriter1, fastQWriter2;
private final Queue<FastQRecord> fastQQueue1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private final Queue<FastQRecord> fastQQueue2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private final int MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 5000;

@Override
public void setOutputFiles(File fastQ1, File fastQ2) {
    try{
        fastQWriter1 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fastQ1));
        fastQWriter2 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fastQ2));
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void writeToFile(FastQRecord one, FastQRecord two) {
    fastQQueue1.add(one);
    fastQQueue2.add(two);
}

@Override
public void close() {
    isRunning = false;

    emptyQueues();

    fastQWriter1.flush();
    fastQWriter1.close();
    fastQWriter2.flush();
    fastQWriter2.close();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    isRunning = true;

    while(isRunning){
        //do stuff
        if(fastQQueue1.size() > MAX_QUEUE_SIZE){ //empty queues - 5000 record pairs at a time

            synchronized (fastQQueue1){
                synchronized (fastQQueue2){
                    emptyQueues();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void emptyQueues() {
    while(fastQQueue1.size() > 0){
        FastQRecord one = fastQQueue1.poll();

        fastQWriter1.println(one.getId());
        fastQWriter1.println(one.getRawSequence());
        fastQWriter1.println(one.getPlus());
        fastQWriter1.println(one.getQualityString());
    }

    while(fastQQueue2.size() > 0){

        FastQRecord two = fastQQueue2.poll();
        fastQWriter2.println(two.getId());
        fastQWriter2.println(two.getRawSequence());
        fastQWriter2.println(two.getPlus());
        fastQWriter2.println(two.getQualityString());

    }
}
}
```

The `FastQRecord` is just a simple POJO that holds the data I need to write to the file:

```
public class FastQRecord {

private String id;
private String rawSequence;
private char plus;
private String qualityString;

public FastQRecord(String id, String rawSequence, char plus, String qualityString) {
    this.id = id;
    this.rawSequence = rawSequence;
    this.plus = plus;
    this.qualityString = qualityString;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getRawSequence() {
    return rawSequence;
}

public void setRawSequence(String rawSequence) {
    this.rawSequence = rawSequence;
}

public char getPlus() {
    return plus;
}

public void setPlus(char plus) {
    this.plus = plus;
}

public String getQualityString() {
    return qualityString;
}

public void setQualityString(String qualityString) {
    this.qualityString = qualityString;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    FastQRecord that = (FastQRecord) o;

    return id.equals(that.id);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id.hashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "FastQRecord{" +
            "id=" + id + '\n' +
            ", rawSequence=" + rawSequence + '\n' +
            ", plus=" + plus + '\n' +
            ", qualityString=" + qualityString + '\n' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Comment: Why wait for the queue to fill up before you start writing to the file?

Comment: Because the writing to the file blocks the threads from appending to the queue

Comment: No it doesn't. The appending is only blocked if the queue is full. Ah, you just seem to be using `BlockingQueue` in a completely wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `BlockingQueue` interface (i.e. blocking a thread if there is no space in the queue) by using the [`put()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#put-E-) method instead of the `add()` one, which is inherited from `Collection`.

But in order to make a thread wait on the `put()` operation, your queue has to know its max size, declaring it as a `LinkedBlockingQueue<>(MAX_QUEUE_SIZE)`. If you don't specify the max capacity of the queue, [it will be assumed it's `Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#LinkedBlockingQueue--)

I also suggest you to synchronize your access on the queue before checking its size (or if it's full) and your `run()` method would look something like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    isRunning = true;

    while(isRunning){
        //do stuff
        synchronized(fastQQueue1){
            if(fastQQueue1.remainingCapacity() == 0){ //empty queues - 5000 record pairs at a time

                synchronized (fastQQueue1){
                    synchronized (fastQQueue2){
                        emptyQueues();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A similar change would be applied to your `emptyQueues()` method.

Comment: Hi Emanuele, thanks for the help. I've implemented your changes, and all seems to work well.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, but take into account [Kayaman's words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578971/asynchronous-queue-based-file-writing/50579261#comment88167404_50578971) : waiting for a queue to fill up before writing to file makes little sense; the writing thread blocking occurs only when the queue is empty, in case you're using `poll()`.

Take a look at the [producer/consumer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem), it might help you have a faster program

Comment: I have made the changes, and the run method now starts writing as long as the remaining capacity does not equal the maximum queue size. i.e as long as there is data in the queue.